# http.jsonp and callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a calculator that will consider AWS instance costs. I am pulling the data from a .js file on amazon and I would like to read it into an object but i keep getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined" .. here is my .js file.

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('formExample', []);

  var ExampleController = function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function(user) {
      $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
      $scope.GetAws();
    };

    $scope.reset = function() {
      $scope.user = "";
    };

    function callback(data) {
      $scope.aws = data;
    }

    $scope.GetAws = function() {
      var url = "http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js?callback=callback";
      $http.jsonp(url);
    };

    $scope.reset();
  };
  app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', ExampleController]);
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is weird that the aws link you are using supports jsonp but it does not take custom callback function name. (Atleast you can look up to find out if the query string they are looking for is `callback` or not). angular handles it when we provide `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` it gets translated to `angular.callbacks_x` which are exposed globally temporarily by angular to handle the request and resolve the promise accordingly. But for this the endpoint must take the callback argument and wrap the response in the same string and function invocation. However this endpoint does not seem to consider it and even without any callback it automatically wraps into default `callback` function invocation. So you would need to inject `$window` (Correct DI way) object and set `callback` function to it and `?callback=callback` is irrelevant.

```
  var ExampleController = function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.master = {};

    //....

    $window.callback = function(data) {
      $scope.aws = data;
    }

    $scope.GetAws = function() {
      var url = "http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js?callback=callback";
      $http.jsonp(url);
    };

    $scope.reset();
   };

   app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', ExampleController]);
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FQggiG?p=preview)**

Comment: See if the query string argument is callback itself or is it expecting a different name.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the one I suggested. I'm actually going to go back to a few apps I've made an update them to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the AWS script is looking to call a function called "callback" on the global scope (outside of Angular). Since your function is within the scope of another (IIFE) function, it cannot be accessed.

What I've done in a case like this is simply put the function in the global scope.

In cases where an application requires some API to have loaded before Angular can do it's magic and has a callback similar to your situation, I have done the following, manually bootstrapping Angular:

**index.html**

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/api?callback=myCallbackFunction"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
// callback function, in global (window) scope
function myCallbackFunction() {

  // manually bootstrap Angular
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
  });

}


// your IIFE
(function() {

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice `callback` should be set in `window` scope.
So,one solution is like:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
  $scope.user = "";
};

window.callback = function(data) {
  $scope.aws = data;
}

$scope.GetAws = function() {
  var url = "http://a0.awsstatic.com/pricing/1/ec2/linux-od.min.js?callback=callback";
  $http.jsonp(url);
};
```